# XSL transformation - XML data to HTML table

Tags: html, xml, xslt, xslt-2.0

Is there way how to create a XSL stylesheet for this type a XML document for output like HTML table on the picture below? The problem is, that generated datas are stored randomly in XML document, so I do not know how to write a stylesheet for it. Can you help me please?

Thank you a lot.

This is a XML document with random sort datas (Memory, CPU0, CPU1, CPU2). This data has two time (time=1 and time=14).

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <root>
        <sample time="14" label="cpu_0">
            <value>22</value>
        </sample>
        <sample time="14" label="cpu_2">
            <value>6</value>
        </sample>
        <sample time="1" label="cpu_2">
            <value>4</value>
        </sample>
        <sample time="14" label="memory">
            <value>97</value>
        </sample>
        <sample time="1" label="cpu_0">
            <value>28</value>
        </sample>
        <sample time="14" label="cpu_1">
            <value>52</value>
        </sample>
        <sample time="1" label="memory">
            <value>55</value>
        </sample>
        <sample time="1" label="cpu_1">
            <value>21</value>
        </sample>
    </root>
```

This is the wanted HTML table output.

[image: Wanted output HTML table]

Comment: What version of XSLT are you using?

Comment: I am using XLST version 2.0.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to do this pretty easily by:

1. Grouping by `track` (using `xsl:for-each-group`).
2. Keeping track of what columns need to be output.

Example...

**XSLT 2.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:output indent="yes"/>
  <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

  <!--Keep track of all CPU columns.-->
  <xsl:variable name="cols" as="item()*">
    <xsl:variable name="init" 
      select="distinct-values(//sample[starts-with(@label,'cpu')]/@label)"/>
    <xsl:perform-sort select="$init">
      <xsl:sort order="ascending" data-type="text"/>
    </xsl:perform-sort>
  </xsl:variable>

  <xsl:template match="/*">
    <html>
      <body>
        <table>
          <thead>
            <tr>
              <th>Time</th>
              <xsl:for-each select="$cols">
                <th><xsl:value-of select="upper-case(replace(.,'_',' '))"/> (%)</th>
              </xsl:for-each>             
            </tr>
          </thead>
          <tbody>
            <xsl:for-each-group select="sample" group-by="@time">
              <xsl:sort select="@time" order="ascending" data-type="number"/>
              <tr>
                <td>
                  <xsl:value-of select="current-grouping-key()"/>
                </td>
                <xsl:for-each select="$cols">
                  <td>
                    <xsl:value-of select="current-group()[@label=current()]"/>
                  </td>
                </xsl:for-each>
              </tr>
            </xsl:for-each-group>
          </tbody>
        </table>
      </body>
    </html>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**Output**

```html
<html>
   <body>
      <table>
         <thead>
            <tr>
               <th>Time</th>
               <th>CPU 0 (%)</th>
               <th>CPU 1 (%)</th>
               <th>CPU 2 (%)</th>
            </tr>
         </thead>
         <tbody>
            <tr>
               <td>1</td>
               <td>28</td>
               <td>21</td>
               <td>4</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
               <td>14</td>
               <td>22</td>
               <td>52</td>
               <td>6</td>
            </tr>
         </tbody>
      </table>
   </body>
</html>
```

See fiddle here: http://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/eiQZDbp

Comment: Yes, it is working! You are the best!

Thank you, realy thank you so much.

Comment: And please one more question, how it change XSL stylesheet if attribute label will has for example this prefix "Test1" and suffix "ok". So the label will look like this label="Test1:cpu_0:ok"?

Comment: @JakubOškera - If they always have at least a prefix, you can use: `upper-case(replace(tokenize(.,':')[2],'_',' '))`. If not, you can use: `upper-case(replace(replace(.,'^([^:]*:)?([^:]+)(:.*)?','$2'),'_',' '))`. Hope this helps!

Comment: I tried both solution but no success. Check here please if I understood right. (http://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/eiQZDbp/1)

Comment: @JakubOškera - Sorry. I forgot to mention you also need to change the starts-with() to a contains() in the `cols` variable. See http://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/eiQZDbp/2

Comment: Yes, it's work. Once more thank you very much, you really helped me a lot.

Comment: Do you know how to do stylesheet for XML code, what JanHradek posted below? I tried something, but no success and it is good question...

Comment: @JakubOškera - J. Hradek should create a new question instead of adding a question as an answer.