# XSL transformation - XML data to HTML table-horizontal

Tags: xml, xslt-2.0

I tried do the same table with XSLT 2.0 like in this question [XSL transformation - XML data to HTML table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49056661/xsl-transformation-xml-data-to-html-table), but I want the output like this - headers will be on left side. [image]

Is there way how to write a stylesheet for this?

XML

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <root>
        <sample time="14" label="cpu_0">
            <value>22</value>
        </sample>
        <sample time="14" label="cpu_2">
            <value>6</value>
        </sample>
        <sample time="1" label="cpu_2">
            <value>4</value>
        </sample>
        <sample time="14" label="memory">
            <value>97</value>
        </sample>
        <sample time="1" label="cpu_0">
            <value>28</value>
        </sample>
        <sample time="14" label="cpu_1">
            <value>52</value>
        </sample>
        <sample time="1" label="memory">
            <value>55</value>
        </sample>
        <sample time="1" label="cpu_1">
            <value>21</value>
        </sample>
    </root>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to create the corresponding HTML table structure:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    expand-text="yes"
    version="3.0">

  <xsl:output method="html" indent="yes" html-version="5"/>

  <xsl:template match="/">
    <html>
      <head>
        <title>.NET XSLT Fiddle Example</title>
        <style xsl:expand-text="no">
            table {
              border-collapse: collapse; width: 100%;
            }
            th, td {
                border-bottom: 1px solid #ddd;
            }
        </style>
      </head>
      <body>
          <xsl:apply-templates/>
      </body>
    </html>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="root">
      <table>
          <tr>
              <td>Time</td>
              <xsl:for-each select="sort(distinct-values(sample/@time))">
                  <td>{.}</td>
              </xsl:for-each>
          </tr>
          <xsl:for-each-group select="sample[starts-with(@label, 'cpu')]" group-by="@label">
              <xsl:sort select="current-grouping-key()"/>
              <tr>
                  <td>{current-grouping-key()}</td>
                  <xsl:for-each select="current-group()">
                      <xsl:sort select="@time"/>
                      <td>{value}</td>
                  </xsl:for-each>
              </tr>
          </xsl:for-each-group>
      </table>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/3Nqn5Yp