# MIN and MAX values and at what time it was

Tags: xml, xslt-2.0

I am reffering to this question [XSL transformation - XML data to HTML table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49056661/xsl-transformation-xml-data-to-html-table). How to find out a min and max values of @label="memory" and @label="cpu" and what @time it was?

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <root>
        <sample time="14" label="cpu_0">
            <value>22</value>
        </sample>
        <sample time="14" label="cpu_2">
            <value>6</value>
        </sample>
        <sample time="1" label="cpu_2">
            <value>4</value>
        </sample>
        <sample time="14" label="memory">
            <value>97</value>
        </sample>
        <sample time="1" label="cpu_0">
            <value>28</value>
        </sample>
        <sample time="14" label="cpu_1">
            <value>52</value>
        </sample>
        <sample time="1" label="memory">
            <value>55</value>
        </sample>
        <sample time="1" label="cpu_1">
            <value>21</value>
        </sample>
    </root>
```

Wantend result

```
MEMORY
syntax: min/max: @value (@time)
min: 55 (1)
max: 97 (14)

CPU
syntax: min/max (CPU_number): @value (@time)
min: (CPU_2): 4 (1)
max: (CPU_1): 52 (14)
```

I am using XSLT 2.0

Comment: USE: max(//sample[@label='memory']/value) or min(//sample[@label='memory']/value)

Comment: Yes, but this gives me just min and max values and not the time when the min or max was also the number of cpu.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you group by the `label` attribute or rather that attribute with the suffix `_digit` stripped for the CPU values and then sort each group by the `value` you can then output the first (min) and last (max) of the sorted group members:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    exclude-result-prefixes="xs"
    expand-text="yes"
    version="3.0">

  <xsl:output method="text"/>

  <xsl:template match="root">
      <xsl:for-each-group select="sample" group-by="replace(@label, '_[0-9]+$', '')">
          <xsl:value-of select="upper-case(current-grouping-key())"/>:
          <xsl:for-each select="current-group()">
              <xsl:sort select="xs:decimal(value)"/>
              <xsl:if test="position() eq 1">
                  min : {value} ({@time})
              </xsl:if>
              <xsl:if test="position() eq last()">
                  max : {value} ({@time})
              </xsl:if>          </xsl:for-each>
      </xsl:for-each-group>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

The above and the online sample https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/pPqsHT1/1 is using XSLT 3 but the grouping and sorting is the same in XSLT 2, you only would need to output any needed data with `xsl:value-of` instead of the text value templates using `{}`.

Comment: Yes it is exactly what I wanted. One more question, can you please implement also average values and time for it?

Comment: Well, computing `avg(current-group()/value)` is easy but I am not sure which time you would then want to relate to that computed average. The average of a number of values is not necessarily one of those values.